# Critique about the quickstart's code in the google-drive documentation

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm learning the quickstart example, on this page https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_4_set_up_the_sample. I understand enough about the code, but i have a doubt about the use of UserRecoverebleAuthIOException.

In the code the method saveFileToDrive() triggers the UserRecoverebleAuthIOException, but only once, and it never happens again in the future, for every re-execution of the app.

So, in a more elegant way, why not triggering the UserAuthIOException and after then calling the saveToDrive() method?

I think that also the didactic aspect is enhanced, in this way.